# Exporting html table to excel file (.xlsx), getting corrupted file on download

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, typescript

I am trying to export html file to .xlsx file but hard luck after downloading, it says corrupted.
It works fine if and able to open for .xls extension, but i need to .xlsx extension.

Below is my code:

```
function convertBase64ToByteArray(base64String: any) {
    const raw = window.atob(base64String);
    const rawLength = raw.length;
    const array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Uint8Array(array);
}

function createBlob(data: any, contentType: any) {
    if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
        return new Blob([data], {
            type: contentType
        });
    }

    throw new Error("Download is not supported");
}

function downloadInternal(blobUrl: any, filename: string) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    if (a.click) {
        a.href = blobUrl;
        a.target = "_parent";
        
        if ("download" in a) {
            a.download = filename;
        }
       
        (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    } else {
        if (window.top === window && blobUrl.split("#")[0] === window.location.href.split("#")[0]) {
            const padCharacter = blobUrl.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";
            blobUrl = blobUrl.replace(/#|$/, padCharacter + "$&");
        }
        window.open(blobUrl, "_parent");
    }
}

function download(blob: any, filename: string) {
    if ((navigator as any).msSaveBlob) {
        
        (navigator as any).msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        return;
    }

    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.downloadInternal(blobUrl, filename);
}

function exportToExcel(headerHtml: any, tableHtml: any, workSheetName: any, downloadFileName: any) {
    const template =
        '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table><tr><td colspan="30">{header}</td></tr><tr><td colspan="30"></td></tr></table>{table}</body></html>';
    const base64 = function (s: any) {
        return window.btoa(s);
    };
    const format = function (s: any, c: any) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (_m: any, p: any) {
            return c[p];
        });
    };

    const ctx = { worksheet: workSheetName || "Worksheet", header: headerHtml, table: tableHtml };
    const data = this.convertBase64ToByteArray(base64(format(template, ctx)));
    const blob = this.createBlob(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    this.download(blob, downloadFileName || "download.xlsx");
}
```

From the js file i call the as below :

```
 const printingHtml = generateHtmlForExport();
                        exportUtil.exportToExcel(headerHtml:
                            " ",
                            tableHtml:printingHtml,
                            WorksheetfileName:"fileName"),
                           downloadfilename:"fileName" + ".xlsx"
                        );
```

If i open the the downloaded file, it shows message as:

Excel cannot opens the file (File Name).xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting HTML strings to XLS through Base64 or blob does not actually export an XLS file, because Excel can open HTML files masquerading as XLS. But the XLSX format is a ZIP file containing multiple XML files, so opening the Html file will cause errors.

This is easy to fix if you can use third-party JavaScript, for example:https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Related questions:[Exporting HTML table to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136662/exporting-html-table-to-xlsx)

Comment: So we cannot export to .xlsx format using blob?

Comment: Blob is available, the error is the HTML file you created, you need to find the third party javascript to generate the correct file.